# Should the Hot wire go through the (switch) first or go to the (light) first?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

I have a circuit that contains a (`fluorescent bulb` w/ a `switch`) + (`outlet-socket`)

The problem is... the bulb light always "shivers".
And the bulb itself gets burned occasionally.

I examined the circuit to figure out the issue and I found that :

- there is a `hot` wire is directly connected to the `bulb`
- and the `neutral` is fed to the `switch`
- that `neutral` is bridged to the `outlet-socket`

The diagram looks something like this :

[image]

Some "local electricians" said that swapping the hot wire from the switch to the bulb causes this issue
(It was just a video on YouTube. not really trustworthy)

However, [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109994/is-it-better-to-wire-power-to-your-switches-or-your-fixtures-first) that is similar to mine had the answers recommend attaching the hot wire to the switch.

It also had this "interesting" comment

> If you run hot to the lights first, then they are hot even if the switch is off. If you do any sort of work on the wiring without turning off the breaker, you stand a good chance of ending your existence. – BillDOe

How?
The circuit is open. How could that happen?
That aligns with what I heard in the video, that this "might" cause the lights to be ON, even if the switch is OFF.

---

**1- Can someone tell me if that is the cause of my problem?**
**2- And how could it be ON while the switch is OFF?**
**3- And why "might"? what makes it behave this way? another underlying issue?**

---

Sorry for the long question.
Thank you for reading this.

---

## UPDATE

I checked the ballast and it was faulty.
It was integrated with the light fitting.
It had no other components whatsoever.
Here is a picture
[image]
I'm not sure what this type is called.
Also, here is the fault :
[image]
One of the resistances got blown apparently and many of the components have this fuzzy-ish green on the legs.

I changed the wiring to the recommended.
and will replace both the ballast and the switch.

Do you recommend a different type of ballast?

Comment: The light might be off with the switch off, but the hot/live wire at the light will always be on/hot.  unless you can float on air, if you touch the light or hot wire and something else, you make a new circuit, with you lighting up instead of the light.  Most people like hot to go to switch first, then a switch hot to light.  Switch neutrals are usually consider bad.

Comment: With the unusual exception, @crip659, where there's a DPDT switch that breaks the neutral _in addition_ to the hot. Those are rare to nonexistent in residential wiring.

Comment: Does the fixture make any audible hum?  Also, can you show how the *cables* are routed?  Wiring is generally done in cables with 2-3 conductors, and their routing matters because this isn't DC power.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in all boxes involved please?

Comment: The biggest problem here is the OP **does not understand how electricity works**, and do not understand the **dangers of connecting neutral to the switch**. I do not have confidence that further troubleshooting is safe. He's working on a live circuit and can kill himself.

Comment: `How? The circuit is open` ... yes it is, until you complete the circuit by touching hot and ground with your hands

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem of why the hot wire is dangerous to humans if it's connected to the light. But the main question is, is it the main culprit for my dead lights?

Comment: @Harper, it doesn't make an audible hum but when I press the switch, it usually doesn't go on automatically. I have to either turn it on and off multiple times or "hit" the switch while on. I know this seems like a switch-related problem but it's new.

Comment: @Nelson, that's partially true. But be assured that I never work with electricity with bare hands and without shutting down the breaker.

Comment: I will try to get a clear photo for wire routing although it's better to draw it. since it's not color-coded and a hell of a mess. But I will see what I can do

Comment: Not sure why all the down votes a question is being asked if this will change the issue!  The answer referred to is not the same as this issue! In the past electricians used switch legs to reduce the amount of wire needed the supply was taken to the light and a switch leg ran down to the switch but the hot was switched so it made no difference. But internet only electricians may guess wrongly that it did. From what I have found is electronic switches usually cause a filament vibration having a filament vibration on a normal snap switch designed is rare with the exception of 60/50 Hz lamps

Comment: You state a fluorescent lamp, is the ballast rated for the actual lamp type you have? I have seen incandescent lamps filament vibrate when dimmers are used I have seen a difference in when the wrong type of lamp was used think rapid start, preheat the lamp must match the ballast not only the wattage but the start type

Comment: @ED , 
`"From what I have found is electronic switches usually cause a filament vibration"`    
Does that indicate it's a switch problem and I need to change it for a new one?   
`"is the ballast rated for the actual lamp type you have?"`  
I will check that out with the rapid start. Thank you for the valuable info. I was just focused on the wiring and didn't think about the actual lamp

Comment: @EdBeal , `"is the ballast rated for the actual lamp type you have?"` how do I know that? Could you please check the post update? I'm not sure how to check whether the components match or not.

Comment: @RooTenshi you have now asked a 2nd, related but totally different question. Please remove your "update" and ask it as a whole new question. Nobody will look down on you for doing so. As a matter of fact the [tour] indicates that this is _exactly_ how we like things here - one answerable question per post! If you'd like, you can reference (use the `share` link below your question text) this question in your new question so you don't have to include _all_ the background in the new post, too.

Comment: Additionally, even though _you_ may not be able to make heads or tails of the wiring in your switch/outlet box on the wall, there are a _lot_ of experienced electricians here who most likely _will_ be able to make sense of it. If they're stumped, they'll be able to ask you more questions based off what they _see_ instead of your _interpretation_ of what's there until they are able to make sense of it.

Comment: @FreeMan , hey thank you for your comment. I just want to clear something. Although it seems like I'm asking a new question, it's still the same question to "why my light goes off?". some Ed recommended it might be the ballast. so I asked how do I know if the ballast is the cause of the *repeated* issue. which is the main point of the post. If you still see it as a different question I will post a new one. I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Internet electricians,,, and now they want to close your question with 4 answers , it’s simple for a real electrician.

Answer (score 0):

each circuit should have it's own hot & neutral wire, the circuit you have drawn looks like they have used a common neutral wire for two separate circuits, (the lighting circuit and the outlet circuit). that's not a good idea and not allowed.

This is how it should be done. the first circuit should have a fuse to the switch:

[image]

Comment: The op knows as little about electrical as you! Your “preferred option would rarely be the way things are wired separately no. the sine wave or S in a circle is the source in an ac circuit. a light is a loop or multiple loops within the circle.  I am guessing here that you both think the thing with 2 circles is a receptacle , no ground? , every circuit must have a hot but some circuits share a neutral called multi wire branch circuits. AC circuits are wired in parallel with switched devices like lights breaking the hot. How many lights can be on 1 circuit ,,, I have seen entire homes on 1 ckt.

Comment: @Ed "Be nice policy".  Also I grasped the yellow S in circle as being the *lamp*, noting the yellow "rays" coming out of it.  Lamps are hard to draw lol.

Comment: Neat. Thanks for the diagram. I checked another room's circuit and it was like the original diagram too. I changed it to the "preferred" version. It had no problem but I changed it anyway. I've yet to change the toilet one (the one w/ the issue) until I figure out where is the fault. 
As for the "Yellow S" yeah that was a mistake on my side. I just did a quick draw and mixed the resistance coil with AC sine wave. I apologize for that mistake.

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  The OP's drawing is fine except for the fact that the hot wire should go to the switch first.    Your first drawing is correct. Your second is a waste of wire